# How to query nested properties using MongoTalk on Pharo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pharo

I’m trying to create a Mongo query on a nested attribute of the doc, in the javascript Mongo shell it would be:

`db.users.find({"services.facebook.email": "some@example.com"})`

How I could execute that query using a query of MongoTalk?

Answer (score 4):

You can query using a “regular” Mongo Query (a.k.a. JSON/Dictionary query) or using `MongoQuery` using `Block` Syntax:

```
mongo := Mongo default.
db := mongo databaseNamed: 'test'.
users := db getCollection: 'users'.

user1 := { 'services' -> {
    'facebook' -> { 'email' -> 'some@example.com' } asDictionary
    }  asDictionary
} asDictionary.

users add: user1.

"Query using dictionary"
users select: {'services.facebook.email' -> 'some@example.com'} asDictionary.

"Query using MongoQuery"
users select: [ :each | (each at: 'services.facebook.email') = 'some@example.com' ].
```

Comment: You can also simply use `users select: {'services.facebook.email' -> 'some@example.com'}`. This might be the closest to your original MongoShell syntax.

Comment: Yeah I've used this suggestion because is the most succinct one. The pairs nneds the `asMongoQuery` or `asDictionary` as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

In Voyage, you have to do something like this:

```
Users selectMany: [ :each | (each at: 'services.facebook.email') = 'some@example.com' ]
```

Since this is MongoQueries, if you are using directly MongoTalk (without Voyage), you can execute the same query in your MongoCollection.

Comment: That's great @EstebanLM thanks for the quick answer!